# what is the relation between coordinate chart and jacobian Transformation?

Tags: differential-geometry

Note : Im newly learning differential Geometry

I have  some  confusion on this  [pdf](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Eizosimov/math534a/Submanifolds.pdf) Page no $:2$

It is written that

> Example $1.5$ (Graphs of smooth functions of one variable). Let $f : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth
> function. Then its graph $\{(x, y) \in R^2
> | y = f(x)\}$ is a smooth $1-$dimensional submanifold of
> $\mathbb{R}^2$

> Proof : let $x_1=x$ and $x_2=y-f(x)$.Then the jacobian of the transformation $(x,y) \to (x_1,x_2)$  is  equal to $1$, so $(x_1,x_2)$  can be taken as  local coordinates  near  any point in  $\mathbb{R}^2$ .In these  coordinates , the  graph $y=f(x) $is given  bythe  equation $x_2 =0$  which  prove  that this  is a smooth  $1$-dimesnional submanifold

**My confusion** :  why are we  taking jacobian  transformation ?

My thinking : Definition of  submanifold  says that  let $M$ be  a manifold of  dimension $m$.A subset $S\subseteq M$ is called a  submanifold  of dimesnion $k \le m$ , if for all $p \in S$   ther  exist a  coordinate  chart $(U ,\varphi)$  around  $p$ such that $\varphi( U \cap S) = \varphi (U) \cap  \mathbb{R}^k$

In the definition of  submanifold jacobian transformation is not mentioned .Then  why are we  taking jacobian  transformation   ?

what is the relation between coordinate chart and jacobian Transformation?

Comment: To check that you have defined a coordinate chart.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm not getting   .what is the relation between coordinate chart and jacobian Transformation?

Comment: What is the definition of a coordinate chart?  Please edit your post to include that.

Comment: @TedShifrin  coordinate chart is a open map